# A bijection between (0,5) and (10,20)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

My teacher gave this question: "Is there a bijection between sets (0,5) and (10,20)" ? I was thinking that it doesn't but I am not exactly sure...could someone clarify ?

Comment: Hint: prove that $f(x)=2x+10$ is a bijection.

Comment: It depends, are these real numbers, rationals, or integers only?

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón I understand f(x) = 2x + 10 is both one to one and onto intuitively b/c it is a line. How do I go about proving it though ? Would showing that it has an inverse f^-1(x) = 0.5(x) -5 be enough ?

Comment: Proving that it has inverse (and that inverse is a function, meaning that it is well defined to each point in the domain) is usually enough.

Comment: @Carlos: What you call a "hint", many would call "the answer".  Maybe you could have engaged with the OP and asked why he thought the answer was negative?

Answer (score 2):

Try $f(x)=2x+10$ - In general, all the open and nonempty subset of $\mathbb R$ has the same cardinal number with $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are talking about real intervals:

First convince yourself that there is a bijection between $(0,5)$ and $(0,10)$. Then, that there is one between $(0,10)$ and $(10,20)$.

Answer (score 0):

Start with one of many bijection (0,1) to (0,1), called f. Compose it f o g with g such that g(x)=1/5 *x. Then multiply the function f o g by 10, and add 10.

Answer (score -1):

> Shroder-Bernstein theorem:
>
> If $(\alpha$  sm $γ)$ and $(β$ sm $δ)$ and $(γ⊂β)$ and $(δ⊂α)$ then $α$ sim $β$.
>
> where "sm" stands for "is similar to" or " has one-to-one(bijective) relation to."

Let $f$ be the relation of $(-11)$, e.g. $0 = f(11), 5=f(16)$, then $(0,5)$ sm $(11, 16)$;

Let $g$ be the relation of $(\times \dfrac{1}{5})$, e.g. $2=g(10), 4= g(20)$ then $(10, 20)$ sm $(2, 4)$.

$(2,4) \subset (0,5)$

$(11,16) \subset (10, 20)$

In virtue of Shroder-Bernstein theorem, $(0,5)$ is similar to $(10,20)$.

Comment: You can use \sim to get $\sim$ if you like it.

Comment: Thanks, @Ross. sm is a symbol I borrowed from Whitehead and Russell's Principia Mathematica. sm stands for one-one relation in PM. It is the same as bijective relation in modern set theory, but I'm not sure whether $ \sm $ has the same meaning in modern mathlog.